# Extends HiveObject in Freezed Hive Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

```
@freezed
class Debt with _$Debt {
 

     @HiveType(typeId: 6, adapterName: 'DebtAdapter')
      const factory Debt({
        @HiveField(0) required Debtor debtor,
        @HiveField(1) List<Item>? items,
        @HiveField(2) List<PaymentRecord>? record,
        @Default(0.0) @HiveField(3) double debts,
        @Default(0.0) @HiveField(4) double balance,
        @Default(false) @HiveField(5) bool isPaid,
      }) = _Debt;
    }
```

I combine the freezed with Flutter Hive, it actually working but my question is how can I extend the HiveObject from Flutter Hive?

Answer (score 1):

```
@freezed
class Debt extends HiveObject with _$Debt {

     Debt._(); //Add this line       

     @HiveType(typeId: 6, adapterName: 'DebtAdapter')
      const factory Debt({
        @HiveField(0) required Debtor debtor,
        @HiveField(1) List<Item>? items,
        @HiveField(2) List<PaymentRecord>? record,
        @Default(0.0) @HiveField(3) double debts,
        @Default(0.0) @HiveField(4) double balance,
        @Default(false) @HiveField(5) bool isPaid,
      }) = _Debt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extend it in the class signature.

```
@freezed
class Debt extends HiveObject with _$Debt {
  ...
}
```

See [this link](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/hive_object) for documentation about HiveObject